# quadrature encoder using photo interrupts

Tags: arduino

I a trying to program an encoder using photo interrupts and a 7474 d flip flop. I believe my wiring is correct. It is simply wiring the photo interrupt to the arduino and having the pin out going through the 7474. Also one of the wires goes to pin 4 to digital read.

Below is my code. For some reason I can't get the photo interrupts to read the turn of the wheel.

```
 const int clock = 0;     //pin 2 is interrupt 0
const int dirPin = 4;    //the number of the LED pin
//const int ledPin =  13;

int count = 0;
int dir = 0;
//int clockA = 0;

void setup(){

  pinMode(dirPin, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  attachInterrupt(clock, program, RISING);

}

void loop()
{


  delay(50);

} 

void program()
{
  dir = digitalRead(dirPin);
  if (dir == HIGH)
  { 
    count ++; 

  }

   else 
   { 
    count --;


   }
   Serial.println(count*30);

}
```

Comment: Please dont just post the arduino playground quadrature encoder website. I dont know why these programs won't work.

Comment: I have wires in pins 2 and 4

Comment: On the 7474 I am in D and clk

Comment: You don't say hardware.  Update the question to indicate the Arduino board type.  attachInterrupt() is different on Due.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the Serial.println() in the interrupt handler.  Inside a handler other interrupts are disabled.  Do as little work as possible and return.  The handler should just update the count and can mark a flag to tell the main loop to process.

```
int count = 0;
int newcounts = 0;

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  if (newcounts) {
    Serial.println(count*30);
    newcounts = 0
  }
}

void program() {
  // ... update count
  newcounts = 1;
}
```